# EF Core 3.1 Fail to query on Json Serialized Object

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, jsonserializer

I used json serialization to store list on ids in a field

Model:

```
public class Video
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<int> AllRelatedIds { get; set; }
}
```

Context:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Video>(entity =>
{
    entity.Property(p => p.AllRelatedIds).HasConversion(
    v => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(v, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore }),
    v => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<int>>(v, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore })
    );
});
```

It works fine, Adding, Editing, Deleting items  is easy and in SQL Database it stores as json like
 `[11000,12000,13000]`

Everything is fine BUT!! as soon as want to query on this list I get weird responses.

**Where:**

`_context.Set<Video>().Where(t=>t.AllRelatedIds.contains(11000))`  returns **null** however if I ask to return all **AllRelatedIds** items some records have 11000 value exp.

**Count:**

`_context.Set<Video>().Count(t=>t.AllRelatedIds.contains(11000))` returns **could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync().**

What's the matter with EF Core? I even tested `t=>t.AllRelatedIds.ToList().contains(11000)` but made no difference

What I should do? I don't want to have more tables, I used this methods hundreds of times but seems never queried on them.

Comment: I'd have to ask what's the matter with this database? Have you tried to store IDs in a JSON field instead of a many-to-many table? That's a clear database design bug. EF is an ORM, it Maps Objects to Relational constructs, it can't do things that are impossible in the database. Using a many-to-many table is easy, clean and manageable. Stuffing everything into a single field is neither, since it violates the most basic design rule - one field, one value. It's now impossible to use SQL to join, filter or query that field

Comment: If you used SQL Server 2016 and later you could use JSON functions (JSON_QUERY, JSON_VALUE) to be able to use that field, and you'd still end up with very bad performance, as those values can't be indexed. If you had a database with array support like Oracle, you could use a `VARRAY` but performance would still suffer

Comment: `I don't want to have more tables,` why? `as soon as want to query on this list ` you don't have a list, you have a long opaque string that some functions can parse. If you design the database properly, you could even use [SQL Server's graph features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/graphs/sql-graph-overview?view=sql-server-ver15) to find related videos, across multiple levels. By using that long string, you can't even query for a single value in SQL

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I didn't want to use too many relations on non-important items and making sql queries, just having them like comma separated seemed enough

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you are right, I have to store them in DB

Comment: That's not how databases work, any of them. Even document databases don't store IDs in fields, they store entire documents. Graph databases explicitly store the graph relations between nodes/items. In relational databases, the *table* specifies a relation between its values. A row isn't an item or object, it's a relation between items.

Comment: The `AllRelatedIds` contains Ids of what? Some other videos? Or something else?

Comment: @atiyar Ids of another tables ( two tables )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Json Serialization/Deserialization happens at application level. EF Core serializes the `IList<int>` object to value `[11000,12000,13000]` *before* sending it to database for storing, and deserializes the value `[11000,12000,13000]` to `IList<int>` object *after* retrieving it from the database. Nothing happens inside the database. Your database cannot operate on `[11000,12000,13000]` as a collection of number. To the database, its a single piece of data.

If you try the following queries -

```cs
var videos = _context.Set<Video>().ToList();
var video = _context.Set<Video>().FirstOrDefault(p=> p.Id == 2);
```

you'll get the expected result, EF Core is doing it's job perfectly.

The problem is, when you query something like -

```cs
_context.Set<Video>().Where(t=> t.AllRelatedIds.Contains(11000))
```

EF Core will fail to translate the `t.AllRelatedIds.Contains(11000)` part to SQL. EF Core can only serialize/deserialize it because you told it to (and how). But as I said above, your database cannot operate on `[11000,12000,13000]` as a collection of integer. So EF Core cannot translate the `t.AllRelatedIds.Contains(11000)` to anything meaningful to the database.

A solution will be to fetch the list of all videos, so that EF Core can deserialize the `AllRelatedIds` to `IList<int>`, then you can apply LINQ on it -

```cs
var allVideos = _context.Set<Video>().ToList();
var selectedVideos = allVideos.Where(t=> t.AllRelatedIds.Contains(11000)).ToList();
```

But isn't fetching ALL videos each time unnecessary/overkill or inefficient from performance perspective? Yes, of course. But as the comments implied, your database design/usage approach has some flaws.